# Can't access filtered results of ngRepeat on controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I've got a ng-repeat grid which it's like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in (filteredResults = (userHours| filter:sortDate | filter:sortYear))">
```

When I apply the filters, they work as expected, however I need to get track of the filtered results to obtain a certain sum of the results, so I added:

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['sortYear','sortDate.data'],function(n,o){
    $scope.sumHours = getHoursSum($scope.filteredResults);
    $scope.sumHours = toHHMMSS($scope.sumHours);
});
```

And I keep getting $scope.filteredResults as "undefined", before or after applying the filters.
What do I need to do to access the filtered results in scope?

Answer (score 1):

I tested it and the issue is due to way you initialize the value :

`ng-repeat` is a directive and you have no idea when it will be `apply` by the angular `digest` cycle. It mean that when your first `$scope.$watch` run, the `ng-repeat` wasn't evaluated yet. It result of `filteredResults` being `undefined`.

The workaround is pretty simple :

- Add the var to your scope at the beginning of the controller.

.

```
$scope.filteredResults = [];
```

You init the collection as an empty array, that will prevent your function running before the `ng-repeat` analyze to encounter an `undefined`

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried it, and I don't get the 'undefined' error again, but if I try to console.log $scope.filteredResults inside $scope.$watch I always get an empty array. I can work around to make it work, but I would like to understand why is it not working this way...

Comment: @CarlosYasuda I may have missed something here. Could you try to reproduce the error in a plunker ? (here is one of mine you can fork and start with http://plnkr.co/edit/EKpWUl85bw8u1DGwhcpC?p=preview)